# Getting error ld.exe: error: cannot find -lgnustl_shared in ndk on compiling tbb source files

Tags: android, opencv, gcc, android-ndk, tbb

I am trying to compile TBB source files from [threadingbuildingblocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/download).

I have tried all available solutions on stackoverflow but none of them works.
The error I am getting is:

```
lib -L/cygdrive/d/Android/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/x86 -lgnustl_shared -shared -Wl,-soname=libtbb.so --sysroot=/cygdrive/d/Android/NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-x86 -m32  -Wl,--version-script,tbb.def
    d:/android/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -ldl
    d:/android/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lgnustl_shared
    d:/android/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lstdc++
    d:/android/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lm
    d:/android/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lc
    d:/android/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -ldl
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    ../../build/Makefile.tbb:127: recipe for target `libtbb.so' failed
    make[1]: *** [libtbb.so] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/OpenCV4Android/workspace_july_2013/TbbLib/jni/build/linux_ia32_gcc_android_cc4.6_release'
    jni/Makefile:40: recipe for target `tbb' failed
    make: *** [tbb] Error 2
```

Here is my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libstdc++
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libstdc++.so
include $(PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

ifeq (armeabi-v7a,$(APP_ABI))
    export SYSROOT:=$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/$(APP_PLATFORM)/arch-arm
else
    export SYSROOT:=$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/$(APP_PLATFORM)/arch-$(APP_ABI)
endif
ifeq (windows,$(tbb_os))
    export CPATH_SEPARATOR :=;
else
    export CPATH_SEPARATOR :=:
endif
export CPATH := $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/$(NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION)/include$(CPATH_SEPARATOR)$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/$(NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION)/libs/$(APP_ABI)/include


export LIB_GNU_STL_ANDROID := $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/$(NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION)/libs/$(APP_ABI)
export CPLUS_LIB_PATH := $(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -L$(LIB_GNU_STL_ANDROID)
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT:=$(NDK_ROOT)
export target_os_version:=$(APP_PLATFORM)
export tbb_tool_prefix:=$(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)


LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DTBB_USE_GCC_BUILTINS -std=c++11
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/include/tbb
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/src/rml/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/include/serial/tbb

CPPFLAGS +="-I$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/include/" \
CFLAGS="-nostdlib" \
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/lib/ -L$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/lib/" \
LIBS="-lc"
LOCAL_PATH := $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/src/tbb
LOCAL_MODULE := tbb
#export MAKE_PATH=D:/Android/NDK/prebuilt/windows/bin
include $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/Makefile
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := concurrent_hash_map.cpp concurrent_vector.cpp dynamic_link.cpp itt_notify.cpp cache_aligned_allocator.cpp queuing_mutex.cpp queuing_rw_mutex.cpp reader_writer_lock.cpp spin_rw_mutex.cpp spin_mutex.cpp critical_section.cpp tbb_misc.cpp tbb_misc_ex.cpp mutex.cpp recursive_mutex.cpp condition_variable.cpp concurrent_monitor.cpp semaphore.cpp rml_tbb.cpp  tbb_statistics.cpp tbb_thread.cpp governor.cpp market.cpp arena.cpp scheduler.cpp observer_proxy.cpp pipeline.cpp tbb_thread.cpp private_server.cpp task_group_context.cpp task.cpp tbb_main.cpp


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is my Application.mk file:

```
export tbb_os?=linux
export compiler?=gcc
export arch?=ia32
export target?=android

ifeq (arm,$(arch))
    APP_ABI:=armeabi-v7a
else
    APP_ABI:=x86
endif
APP_PLATFORM:=android-9
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:=4.6
APP_STL :=gnustl_shared
```

Please let me know if I should add some other file here to let you understand the issue.

Comment: Why not use the binary version packaged into the linux version of TBB (doesn't answer your question)

Comment: Thanks Samveen for your reply. Can you please elaborate with some links how can I do so ?

Comment: The [TBB Download page](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/download) mentions something about the Linux version of TBB containing libraries for even android. (search android on the download page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that it was trying to load libraries from the path

```
 -L/cygdrive/d/Android/NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/lib 
 -L/cygdrive/d/Android/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/x86
```

which is indeed right location on my drive but not correct path on Windows.

I had to hardocde this part of the code with Windows understandable path text as:

```
-LD:/Android/NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/lib 
-LD:/Android/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/x86
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple libraries cannot be found. Try to find out where these libraries are located on your system.

In the makefile, this path is added to LD_FLAGS for the linker to search:

```
-L$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/lib/
```

First, check if the required libraries can be found there (e.g. libm.so)

If not, try to find out whether they are somewhere else on your system. On Linux, libdl.so, libm.so etc. can be found in /usr/lib64 (/usr/lib on a 32-bit system). If you find them, add the path to LDFLAGS as for the path above:

```
-L/path/to/libs
```